# Text Compare in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, comparison

I need to compare two cell strings with text content. I tried, `=FIND()` and VBA like function. Also I played around with substitute and `LEFT()`, `RIHT()` to get to a common ground. However I can't apply the same method all across the board.

A good example:

```
**Column A**    BENEX LIMITED

**Column B**    BENEX LTD
```

Comment: This question is better asked on http://superuser.com/. I guess you might be looking for [soundex comparison](http://www.j-walk.com/ss/excel/tips/tip77.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Could you confirm that you are simply trying to determine whether the text string in column A exists within the string in column B? If this what you are after you could just use the 'SEARCH' function.

```
Where:

Cell A1 = Benex
Cell B1 = Benex Ltd

=SEARCH(A1,B1,1)
```

If the string within cell A1 is contained with the string in cell B1 a value greater than zero will be returned (this value indicate the position of the match).

If this is not quite what you are after could you expand a little on your question?